# INNER JOIN uses AND?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to INNER join 3 tables.  1st JOIN (alone) works perfect and returns the expected 3 rows.  I then add another join to say match a name column from a third table.  I would expect just 3 rows again but NO.  I get back a TON of rows.

My question is, do JOINs build off of each other?  1st INNER JOIN gives us results_1 ... 2nd INNER JOIN on results_1 gives results_2 ... 3rd INNER JOIN on results_2 and so on?? Is this true?

```
select
students.*
FROM classes
INNER JOIN students ON students.id = classes.id
INNER JOIN books ON books.obj_num_position = students.object_table_obj_num_pos_ref
```

I find myself falling back to using FROM X Y Z ... and WHERE x.id = z.id AND WHERE AND WHERE ..... instead of explicit joins as its easier to troubleshoot

Comment: Post your table structure too, which could ensure better answers below.

Comment: Implicit joins _are not_ easier to troubleshoot. You're far less likely to make a mistake using explicit joins because certain behaviour is impossible; (syntax errors will be raised). The answer to your question is yes; you get a ton of rows because a ton of rows match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `INNER JOIN` will return as many rows as there are matches across the three tables. In your case, it would seem that `students.object_table_obj_num_pos_ref`  has a *one-to-many* relationship with `books.obj_num_position`, and therefore returns every `books.obj_num_position` matching any `students.object_table_obj_num_pos_ref` having one of the `students.id` returned in the previous `JOIN` with `classes`.

If you need to limit to a subset of these, the way to do so is still via a `WHERE` clause, in which you specify the limiting condition.

By the way, if you used an implicit join with no conditions other than the joining conditions in the `WHERE` clause, you would get exactly the same result.

Comment: So is there an order of operations?  It sounds like the INNER JOINs work for everything (top to bottom or bottom to top .. doesn't matter) and I'm assuming the WHERE(s) get added once ALL the joins are done?  True?

Comment: That's conceptually correct.  The `WHERE` clause filtering is applied to the rowset as it would be after all the `JOIN`s have taken place.  The RDBMS may be able to optimize the where clause earlier however, so that it is only joining against matched rows, however.